# How to make sure a form is posted only after an upload through browser button is completed

Tags: html, forms, file, post, submit

I have an HTML form with a text input named "name", file upload input named "myFile" (shows Browse button), and a submit button (named "Upload").

I accidentally pressed enter before I choose a file, and a file with 0 length was uploaded to the servlet.  How to make sure the browser doesn't post if the file is not selected, or the file name is empty...  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to catch the form's `submit` event, otherwise you'll only be able to check on the server-side. I'm assuming that's okay (because it's not really *optional*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David, your comment is correct.  The answer is to use javascript to check whether the text input is filled with info if manual input is required.  I also could use the javascript to put the file name without the path to fill in the form automatically.